# JFET self bias, choosing source resistor so that the operating point is (1/2, 1/4)

Tags: jfet

When \$R_s=R_{DS} = \frac{-V_{GS(OFF)}}{I_{DSS}}\$, my textbook seems to suggest that \$I_{D}\$ equals \$\frac{I_{DSS}}{4}\$, but I'm not able to derive this. Any help?

My work:
\$I_D = I_{DSS}(1-\frac{V_{GS}}{V_{GS(OFF)}})^2 \$

\$V_{GS} = -I_DR_s = I_D\frac{V_{GS(OFF)}}{I_{DSS}} \implies \frac{V_{GS}}{V_{GS(OFF)}}= \frac{I_D}{I_{DSS}}\$

[Solving](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bqfdwchntw) these two equations (parabola, straight line) gives me
$$\frac{I_D}{I_{DSS}} = \frac{3 \pm  \sqrt{5}}{2} $$

\$\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 0.38 \ne \frac{1}{4}\$

---

What does the author mean when he says the drain current will be \$1/4\$  of \$I_{DSS}\$ and \$V_{GS}\$ will be half the cutoff voltage?

From my work, the operating point has equal ratios:  \$\color{purple}{(0.38V_{GS(OFF)}, 0.38I_{DSS})}\$

I don't see how the operating can ever be \$\color{red}{(\frac{1}{2}V_{GS(OFF)}, \frac{1}{4}I_{DSS})}\$  as the author claims.

---

[image]

Comment: textbook source: https://archive.org/details/ElectronicPrinciples8thEdition/page/424/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: They are discussing the ratio of Id to Idss (and I know you know that much already from your writing above) vs the **ratio** of Vgs to Vgsoff. In short, if \$A=\frac{I_D}{I_{DSS}}\$ and \$B=\frac{V_{GS}}{V_{{GS}_{OFF}}}\$ then \$A=\left(1-B\right)^2\$. No need to solve two equations simultaneously to know that when \$B=\frac12\$ that \$A=\frac14\$. Solve them simultaneously if not looking to compare the ratios but instead computing the actual intersection, given some curve. But expect different values for different curves.

Comment: \$B=1/2\$ gives \$A=1/4\$. I'm fine with this. But the author is saying  this happens  when the source resistor value is \$\frac{V_{GS(OFF)}}{I_{DSS}}\$

Comment: Which is clearly wrong because, in self bias \$V_{GS} = -I_D*R_s\$

Comment: When I set \$ R_s = \frac{V_{GS(OFF)}}{I_{DSS}} \$ , I get \$ V_{GS} = -I_D* \frac{V_{GS(OFF)}}{I_{DSS}}\$

Comment: But that is same as saying the ratios are equal:    \$B = A\$

Comment: \$\dfrac{1}{2} \ne \dfrac{1}{4}\$ I'm confused what the author means @jonk

Comment: In short:  The author says \$R_s = \frac{V_{GS(OFF)}}{I_{DSS}}\$ gives the operating point \$(1/2, 1/4)\$.  But my work shows the operating point has to be \$(0.38, 0.38)\$. Who is correct @jonk

Comment: Perhaps you should write a little more in your question, rather than writing it all down in comments. But looking forward in the text I see where you get your equation from the author. I can *also* see where that term comes from in the simultaneous solution, too. If you solve for Id and then divide that by Idss to get the ratio, you should see there is a factor of (Vgsoff/Idss) in the result. But it is not the only factor. So I am not sure I can explain their claim, just yet.

Comment: Oh sorry I'll update the question, thank you so much for taking time to understand my question. I notice:  setting \$R_s=\frac{V_{GS(OFF)}}{I_{DSS}}\$ is same as solving  the system of equations:   \$A = (1-B)^2\$ and \$A=B\$

Comment: @jonk updated the question... hope it is clear now thanks again!

Comment: Start with \$\frac{I_{_\text{D}}}{I_{_\text{DSS}}}=\left(1-\frac{V_{_\text{GS}}}{V_{_{{\text{GS}\,}_\text{OFF}}}}\right)^2\$, \$V_{_\text{GS}}=-R_{_\text{S}}\,I_{_\text{D}}\$, and \$R_{_\text{S}}=\frac{-V_{_{{\text{GS}\,}_\text{OFF}}}}{I_{_\text{DSS}}}\$ (their claim on the following page.) Then the claim they make is this: $$\frac{I_{_\text{D}}}{I_{_\text{DSS}}}=\left(1-\frac{R_{_\text{S}}\,I_{_\text{D}}}{R_{_\text{S}}\,I_{_\text{DSS}}}\right)^2=\left(1-\frac{I_{_\text{D}}}{I_{_\text{DSS}}}\right)^2$$

Comment: But \$\frac{I_{_\text{D}}}{I_{_\text{DSS}}}\ne \left(1-\frac{I_{_\text{D}}}{I_{_\text{DSS}}}\right)^2\$, even as, for example, a Taylor's approximation around \$\frac14\$. Not even close. Are we on the same page, here?

Comment: Yes \$x =  (1-x)^2\$ is not an identity it is true only for two values: \$x = \frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\$

Comment: So where do you want to go from here? I think we agree where their claim leads.

Comment: I'm just confused is all...  you agree the claim by author is incorrect?guess im back to sanity xD @jonk

Comment: I don't see how to escape the conflict. The only remaining thing to do is to try and run a set of simulations with a Spice program to verify your conclusion. If Spice shows their claim to be correct, then both you and I are back to the drawing board. If Spice confirms your conclusion, then you have found an error in a textbook.

Comment: Ok it helps a lot that you confirm I didn't make an error in understanding the textbook. I have LTSpice.. I'll simulate later. But I have more clarity now after discussing with you. Thank you so much you're awesome!

Comment: It is frustrating the author uses the same approximation in many example problems https://prnt.sc/zDMzvEVCUIBN

Comment: I think you followed it well! But then I'd think that since I agree with you. So my opinion doesn't add anything new and is therefore worthless. ;)

Comment: @jonk  ... I have some explanation after simulating ... In fact, I "found" that RDS (defined as RDS=Vgs_off/Idss) is the value of the **"dynamic"** resistance at the chosen Quiet Point (???) Q point in ratios (1/2,1/4).

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks! Excellent catch! But I'd love it if you wrote more, including the equation derivations so that it is captured here. :) Makes a LOT of sense. Spice should be able to capture the slope at that point with .MEAS card, I think.

Comment: @jonk Done. It was really a good question. I remembered me  ~ 50 years ago :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simulation with generic JFET.
At the left, the characteristic (Id vs Vg) is traced.
An after, also load line.
At the right, test with the values found of Idss.

[image]

EDIT: ***NB: Chosen points are not the same as above. (Vgsoff = -3V, Idss = 5mA)***
As I was curious about the OP question, I made also a simulation with the theoretical function.
And the result seems that "RDS" is 600 Ohm = 3 V/ 0.005 mA.

[image]

But, I have some explanation after simulating ...
In fact, I "found" that **RDS** (defined as \$RDS = Vgs_off/Idss\$) is :
the value of the **"dynamic" resistance** at the chosen Quiet Point,
Q point in ratios (\$Vgs = 1/2 * Vgsoff, Id = 1/4 * Idss\$).

**Graphical construction:**

1. draw the **line** through the two characteristic points of the graph **(Vgsoff and Idss)**.
2. Draw the tangent to the point of contact with the parabola
   at **(Vgs = 1/2 * Vgsoff, Id = 1/4 Idss)**. This tangent is **parallel** to the other line and is, by definition, the **dynamic resistance** at the contact point.

[image]

This is confirmed by my calculus with Maple sheet.
Calculate the **derivative** (or measure it on graph) at the quiet point, and the value is exactly RDS.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice graphs! I have a question... Is  `636.947` ohm value the same as `VGSOFF/IDSS` ?  but from the slope of red-line it seems you're using `1600` ohm resistor at source? Also did you use datasheet to find the value of `VGSOFF/IDSS` ?

Comment: Right. The second graph is ok, I think. I must correct the first, I made a "little" error ("*" replaced by "/") in the function of the load line. (not simple when the graph is on the negative x-axis ...)

Comment: Wow these are simply awesome! which tool you're using to plot these graphs? matlab?  From these graphs it seems when \$R_s = 2*R_{DS} = 1200\$ ohm, we have the Q point in ratios \$(1/2, 1/4)\$. that is in actual values \$(-1.5, 1.25)\$ very enlightening! thank you so much!

Comment: Simulations made with microcap v12 free software http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Comment: >>> Is 636.947-ohm value the same as VGSOFF/IDSS? <<< All values came from the graph, for a generic JFET with some parameters I did not change, just measured on graph by software (function Idss_peak ...).

Comment: @across See my updated answer ... for the "explanation" of RDS.

Comment: I feel you've just demonstrated the Mean Value Theorem : instantaneous rate equals average rate at some point. Average rate of current in the interval \$(V_{gsoff},0)\$ is \$\frac{I_{DSS}}{V_{gsoff}}\$. Instantaneous rate of current is

$$\frac{dI_D}{dV_{gs}} = \frac{d}{dV_{gs}} I_{DSS}(1-\frac{V_{gs}}{V_{gsoff}})^2 = I_{DSS}\cdot 2\cdot(1-\frac{V_{gs}}{V_{gsoff}})(\frac{-1}{V_{gsoff}}) = \frac{2I_{DSS}}{V_{gsoff}^2}(V_{gs}-V_{gsoff})$$

Comment: When \$Vgs=\frac{V_{gsoff}}{2}\$, that expression equals \$\frac{I_{DSS}}{V_{gsoff}}\$ and this is the maximum possible conductance for the jfet in ohmic region! Wow! so the author isn't entirely inaccurate haha Thanks again:)